# "cstdarg file not found" when running jextract on the C binding for a Rust project

Tags: java, rust, ffi, project-panama

I'm trying to get a simple integer addition function written in Rust working with Java's Project Panama. Having generated the bindings using `cbindgen` crate, I get the following error when running jextract:

```
jextract -t org.adder -L . -l adder-java --record-library-path -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdarg bindings.h -o adder-java.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException: /Users/ash/Code/adder/bindings.h:1:10: fatal error: 'cstdarg' file not found
```

I've looked at [the examples given](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/panama/dev/raw-file/foreign/doc/panama_foreign.html), but can't decipher what I'm getting wrong.

Here is my library file:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn addition(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
    a + b
}
```

And the generated bindings (will also need sources for `cstdint`, `cstdlib` and `new` I presume?):

```cpp
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

extern "C" {

uint32_t addition(uint32_t a, uint32_t b);

} // extern "C"
```

What do I need to do to get `jextract` to find these files?

Comment: same issue but not in the project, what is jextract?

Comment: jextract is a simple tool which generates a Java API from one or more native C headers - https://github.com/openjdk/panama-foreign/blob/foreign-jextract/doc/panama_jextract.md

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: I don't recall any longer. My reason for wanting this was for a hobby project that I no longer have time to work on.

Answer (score 2):

The correct command is `jextract -C -x -C c++ -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1 -t adder -o adder.jar bindings.h`.

Pass `-x c++` to clang, include the path specified by `-I`.