# Fatal error "'stdlib.h' file not found" when running jextract on the C binding for a Rust project

Tags: java, rust, ffi, project-panama

I want to use Project Panama's `jextract` tool to build a Java binding to a Rust library. When running the following command, I get an error:

```
jextract -C -x -C c++ -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1 -t adder -o adder.jar bindings.h
java.lang.RuntimeException: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:93:15: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
```

I'm confused because the include path contains `stdlib.h`:

```
ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ | grep stdlib                                        
cstdlib
stdlib.h
```

The line in error contains only `#include_next <stdlib.h>`.

My Rust source is a simple function:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn addition(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
    a + b
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn adds() {
        assert_eq!(addition(1, 2), 3);
    }
}
```

The `bindings.h` header is generated by the `cbindgen` crate:

```cpp
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

extern "C" {

uint32_t addition(uint32_t a, uint32_t b);

} // extern "C"
```

What do I need to do for `jextract` to locate `stdlib.h`?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Is this not solved by the same techniques as your previous question [“cstdarg file not found” when running jextract on the C binding for a Rust project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62760145/155423)? Are you going to ask the same question for each unique header in your project? Please [edit] your question to deliberately link to your previous question and clarify how this question differs.

Comment: I'm not. I thought it was a different issue when I posted. Having looked into it some more, it's broadly similar.

Comment: @NomadMaker this is OpenJDK [Project Panama](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/panama/). The jextract tool is provided by the JDK.

Comment: Jextract is a tool. If you're using a drill, do you include the "steel" and "plastic" tags because the drill is made of steel and plastic?

Comment: @NomadMaker perhaps you could propose a more appropriate set of tags that the OP should have used instead? You can probably even do so in an [edit].

Comment: No idea why this question was voted down, but the solution to this question helped me fix a problem. Keep asking!

Answer (score 3):

This was a case of missing an include path - I needed to include the MacOS SDK stdlib.h header file location also. This wasn't clear from the error.

The correct command to have run was:

```
jextract -C -x -C c++ -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1 -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -t adder -o adder.jar bindings.h
```

Comment: I had built LLVM locally and was getting this error (having worked fine last week). Adding `-I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1 -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include` made it work,